# when i run the exe i get No module named 'PyQt5' but from the script its work

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe, pyinstaller

i use windows 10, python 3.7 and pyinstaller version 3.5.

I wrote some script in pycharm and when i hit run (from the pycharm IDE) its work fine.

but when I execute it by pyinstaller to exe ("pyinstaller --onefile design.py"),

I click the file inside the dist folder (design.exe) and i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "design21.py", line 10, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
[11116] Failed to execute script design21
```

my code start with:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui_with_layouts.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread,pyqtSignal
from style import *
from firebase import firebase
import xlrd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


stop_flag = False
```

**UPDATE:**

I dont know how but i did the next step and somehow it work:

1. delete line 10 and 11 (that import the 'Pyqt5')
2. execute new exe (from cmd the commend `pyinstaller --onefile design21.py`)
3. run the new exe file from the dist folder (Of course I got errors, because I used the moudle 'Pyqt5' without importing it).
   4.add again the import line (that lines that i deleted 10 and 11).
4. execute again new exe (from cmd the commend `pyinstaller --onefile design21.py`)
   then when I run the new exe it work...
   no idea why but its worked.

Comment: Please include all _relevant_ code, especially the first ten lines of the file `design21.py`.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

you need to install **pyqt5**.

just open **CMD** and install it.

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: requirement already satisfied, yet I get the error message that it is not installed.
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.15.7)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pyqt5) (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.11.0)

Answer (score 0):

No module named 'PyQt5'  here not PyQt5 not installed on python environment install correctly or use the right python environment.

Pycharm editor goto project setting and choose python environment with  'PyQt5'

OR pycharm bottom CMD install a `pip install PyQt5`

Comment: I did installed correctly the 'PyQt5' by pip install 'PyQ5t', from the CMD.

Comment: any Error you geting ?

Comment: no error.
the moudle  'PyQ5t' was installed successfully,
the Exact proof is that it work fine from the pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. For me importing sip in the first line of the programm solved the issue:

from PyQt5 import sip